# Play Framework on GAE, outdated?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, playframework, web-frameworks

I was considering using the Play! framework on Google App Engine for a simple to medium complexity web application.

It looks like I am limited to Play 1.x. The GAE module 1.6.0 is supporting GAE SDK 1.6.0 and when installing it says it supports Play 1.2.4. The Siena module 2.0.6 says it supports Play 1.2.3.

I feel like the whole setup I am thinking about is completely outdated and the components are not active at all. Is that the case? This will be a production web application that will be used by hundreds of thousands, I can't afford any integration issues or bugs that won't be fixed by updating the framework or the modules just because there are no new releases. I feel very limited with this setup.

I can't change GAE as the platform but I can choose any other framework with better support, the only reason I was thinking about Play is because it seems flexible, easy to learn, fast to develop and not bloated. I don't have the time to spent/waste on understanding and configuring frameworks like Spring or similar.

So, am I right thinking this is a bad choice? And if yes, what would you recommend for a Java developer on GAE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to consider Groovy, how about [Gaelyk](http://gaelyk.appspot.com/)?

Comment: I am open to try everything at this point, so I will certainly take a look. Looks promising and the syntax not that hard to get used to.